# Proof of an inequality with a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am trying to show that for every $\lambda \in (-\pi,\pi)\setminus\{0\}$ and every $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(n-1)\lambda}{1-\cos\lambda}} \leq 1$$

This inequality came up in my study of spectral densities of time series. I am not entirely sure whether it is true. I did a quick numerical analysis and it "seems" true. Is there a clever trick to show its validity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

- $\cos x = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \frac x2$ for $x \in \Bbb R$,
- $|\sin(nx)| \le n |\sin x|$ for $x \in \Bbb R$, $n \in \Bbb N$,

it follows that

$$
\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(n-1)\lambda}{1-\cos\lambda}} =
\frac{1}{n} \left | \frac{\sin(n-1)\frac \lambda 2}{\sin \frac \lambda 2} \right | 
\le \frac{n-1}{n} < 1 \, .
$$